# Android - Como ativar e desativar o wifi

Tags: java, android

Tenho um app em java com dois botoes. Como fazer para quando apertar o primeiro o wifi seja ativado, e quando apertar o segundo ele ser desativado?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a classe `WifiManager` e atráves do método `setWifiEnabled` consegue habilitar e desabilitar a wifi, a documentação oficial pode se encontrada [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled(boolean)).

Para isso você deve adicionar a permissão no manifesto do seu aplicativo.

No seu AndroidManifest.xml adicione a seguinte permissão:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

e no seu programa implementar:

```
   WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
   wifi.setWifiEnabled(false); //desabilita
   wifi.setWifiEnabled(true); //habilita
```

Comment: Estava convencido que isso já não era possível nas versões mais recentes do Android.

Comment: Pode me ajudar?o codigo funcionou mas quando toco ligar ele funciona perfeitamente, mas exibe a mensagem o app "parou" como corrijo?

Comment: e quando faco para desligar o wifi exibe a mesma mensagem mas nao desliga

Comment: @ramaral funciona com o bluetooth também, único que não funciona deste modo, é o GPS, não sei o porque..

Comment: @Drkill32 Qual erro que ocorre? pode postar aqui?

Comment: Quando toco o botao ligar o wifi e ativado. Porem o app se fecha sozinho...

Comment: Mas você consegue postar o log do adb, para ver o erro??

Comment: Desculpe adb? Pelo que sei nao tem log. Estou testando diretamente pelo smartphone

Comment: Você está utilizando qual IDE para programar? Se for o Intelijj ou Android Studio basta debugar o app, vai aparecer o console com os eventos da aplicação.

Comment: estou programando pelo proprio android pois meu PC nao esta funcionando. Estou usando o AIDE

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni Com o GPS já funcionou mas foi retirado por questões de segurança e confidencialidade: qualquer programa podia ligar o GPS e monitorizar a localização do usuário sem ele saber.

Comment: @Drkill32 Não sei como ver os logs no AIDE, utilizei ele apenas quando foi lançado para fazer um 'hello word', sem os logs não tem como saber o que está acontecendo.. :/